# Python-like unpacking of numeric value in R

Tags: r, iterable-unpacking

In Python, one can do this:

```
>>> a, b, c = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
```

Is there a way to do it in R, as below?

```
> a, b, c = c(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: Well, ten years later but you can use the zeallot package.

Comment: @FrishMagmol too bad the question was duplicated, I'd love to have it as an answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this within a list using `[<-`

```
e <- list()

e[c('a','b','c')] <- list(1,2,3)
```

Or within a data.table using `:=`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table()
DT[, c('a','b','c') := list(1,2,3)]
```

With both of these (lists), you could then use `list2env` to copy to the global (or some other) environment

```
list2env(e, envir = parent.frame())

a
## 1
b
## 2
c
## 3
```

But not in general usage creating objects in an environment.

Comment: Nice... wasn't aware of `list2env` - though I can see it being abused rather than used.

Comment: Actually, I will not use `list2env()` - it seems rather hackish and unnatural in R - but the answer is instructive and comprehensive nonetheless. Also, I learned how to use lists! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

maybe it looks stupid, but I would do this :

```
v <- list(a=0,b=0,c=0)
v[] <- c(1,2,3)
 v
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3
```