# Tuple unpacking in R

Tags: r, tuples

Python has the `*(...)` syntactic sugar.  Can you do this in R?

> ```
> t = (2010, 10, 2, 11, 4, 0, 2, 41, 0)
> dt = datetime.datetime(*t[0:7])
> ```

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2238361/1007926

This allows each element of the tuple to be assigned to an argument of, in this case, the `datetime` function.

An analogous trick in R might look like this, if the syntax were the same as Python:

```
lims <- c(10,20)
my.seq <- seq(*lims)
```

---

I don't believe this exactly the same as "unpacking" used in this question:

> ```
> >>> a, b, c = (1, 2, 3)
> ```
>
> Is there a way to do it in R, as below?
>
> ```
> a, b, c = c(1, 2, 3)
> ```

[Python-like unpacking of numeric value in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15170394/1007926)

Comment: What exactly is the question here?  What do you expect as the result?  Not all of us know Python.

Comment: Okay.  I think I've clarified a bit.  Thanks

Comment: Not clear yet.  In `R`, the order of arguments to a function need not be fixed.  Are you asking for this? -->  function defined as `foo(x,y,z,k,l,m)` and you want to assign the values of an object `bar[1:6]` to the arguments of `foo` ?   If so, take a look at `?formals` to see if it'll do what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of is `do.call`:

```
> lims <- c(10,20)
> do.call(seq, as.list(lims))
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

But do note that there are some subtle differences in evaluation that may cause some function calls to be different than if you had called them directly rather than via `do.call`.

Comment: Can wrap that in a functional wrapper: `tun = function(f){function(...){do.call(f,as.list(...))}}` then `tun(seq)(lims)` works.